# Get top tags from SQL db

Tags: php, sql

I have the following table:

```
id tag   imgID ts
1  funny   1   2013-03-03 09:56:56
1  boring  5   2013-03-03 09:56:56
1  cute    3   2013-03-03 09:56:56
1  funny   67   2013-03-03 09:56:56
```

For tags of images.  So this was the best solution I could come up with, so when ever a tag is added, a new line is added onto this table.  So there could be many lines with many of the same tags.  What I want to do is to show the top ten most used tags on the homepage.  So if there are many tags for funny, and it is trending, I want that to be number one.  How can I do this with SQL?

Comment: I suggest you first change the table structure by normalizing. I see a lot of data can be redundant. `TagTable(Id, TagName)` and `ImageTagMapper(ID, TagTableID, ImageID, TimeSeconds)` Then use join on the tables and fetch first 10 results.

Comment: @LearningByCoding I'd love to, but you've confused me - what do you mean by tagtable() and imagetagmapper() ?

Comment: @Chud37 They are the table names. I see you might have just one table here. Create two separate tables.  [Normal Forms](http://www.trumpetpower.com/Papers/Normal_Forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` to group all rows by tag, and then list them in order of frequency in your table.

```
SELECT tag
FROM theTable
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Is this going to be slow when there's hundreds of thousands of tags in there?

Answer (score 0):

By grouping and counting:

```
SELECT    tag, COUNT(*) occurrences
FROM      yourtable
GROUP BY  tag
ORDER BY  occurrences DESC
```

Doing `GROUP BY` statements on string columns isn't a very good solution however. You should normalize your database structure and extract tags into a separate table.